# F ind the $\lim_{x \to 0^-} \dfrac{x(2\lfloor x \rfloor +2x\lfloor 1/x\rfloor )}{\cos 2x-1}$ .

Tags: calculus

F ind the  $\lim_{x \to 0^-} \dfrac{x(2\lfloor x \rfloor +2x\lfloor 1/x\rfloor )}{\cos 2x-1}$ .

my try : $\lim_{x \to 0^-} \dfrac{(2\lfloor x \rfloor +2x\lfloor 1/x\rfloor )}{4x}\times \dfrac{4x^2}{\cos 2x -1}=(1/2\dfrac{\lfloor x \rfloor}{x}+1/2\lfloor 1/x \rfloor) \times (\dfrac{4x^2}{\cos 2x -1}) \\ =1/2 (\lfloor 1/x \rfloor-1/x)\dfrac{4x^2}{\cos 2x -1}$ .

now I know that $\lim_{x \to 0^-} \dfrac{4x^2}{\cos 2x -1}=-1/2$
but I dont know $\lim_{x \to 0^-} 1/2 (\lfloor 1/x \rfloor-1/x)$

Answer (score 1):

Close to $0^-$, $\lfloor x\rfloor=-1$ and

$$\lim_{x \to 0^-} \dfrac{x\left(2\lfloor x \rfloor +2x\left\lfloor \dfrac1x\right\rfloor \right)}{\cos 2x-1}=\lim_{x \to 0^-} \dfrac{x\left(-2x\dfrac1x+2x\left\lfloor \dfrac1x\right\rfloor \right)}{\cos 2x-1}=\lim_{x \to 0^-} \dfrac{ -2x^2\left\{\dfrac1x\right\}}{\cos 2x-1}$$

As the denominator is asymptotic to $-2x^2$, the limit does not exist.

Comment: how prove that $ \lim_{x \to 0^-} 1/x -\lfloor 1/x \rfloor =\text{does not exist}$?

Comment: @justin32: $\{\frac1x\}$ is an arbitrary number in $[0,1)$.

Answer (score 0):

$$L=\lim_{x\to 0^-} \frac{x([2x]+2x[1/x])}{\cos 2x-1}=\lim_{h \to 0} \frac{h([-2h]-2h[-1/h])}{\cos 2h -1}=\lim_{h \to 0} \frac{[-2h]-2h[-1/h])}{-h/2}$$
$$\implies L=\lim_{h\to 0} \frac{-1+2h}{-h/2}=\infty.$$